# How exactly to calculate your next time slot for baking?

Tags: baking, node, baker

[This post](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/844/how-to-become-a-baker-what-are-all-the-technical-financial-requirements) already answered my question whether it is possible for a baker to predict her NEXT time slot. The answer was YES. Now I would like to know exact precise information as a follow-up on that:

Can you please explain, **how** exactly I can predict my next time slot, in practical terms - I mean, what is the calculation to get as a result for example XX-hours/XX-days, or XX-block-level?

If I have a baking node today: how to know at which ##block-level (or after how many hours) it will be my turn to bake?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/419/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-baking-rights-for-a-wallet-address-using-the-rpc-api) answer your question?

Comment: I mean... how accurate do you want to be? It is going to be impossible to predict the exact time with high confidence. The baking rights RPC gives you some idea, but it is not accurate: you will see the timestamps moving forward as the rights get closer. If you describe this problem in your question, I may attempt to describe a solution.

Comment: hi I have not a current problem to describe. I just want to know, IF a baker starts his full node in order to solobake:  how can she know/calculate the NEXT ##blocklevel at which she would have a turn to bake?  

question for me is, what calculation formula is there ? or is there already a fixed waiting period , like xxx-blocks, or xxx-hours ?   What is the waiting time and how to calculate it /currently   , @Tom